# ActiveRecord: is it possible do a join relation with a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here is my original problem. I have two models as below.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

and

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
end
```

I would like to left join Author to Book's scope "available". Following is the query I would like to execute on DB. Is it possible to do this ?

```
Select authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count 
From authors left outer join books on books.author_id = authors.id 
and books.available = true 
group by (authors.id) order by books_count;
```

I have tried following method

```
 Author.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN authors on books.author_id = authors.id")
.merge(Book.available)
.select("authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count")
.group("authors.id").order("books_count")
```

But that result in following query.

```
Select authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count 
From authors left outer join books on books.author_id = authors.id 
where books.available = true 
group by (authors.id) order by books_count;
```

So it remove all the authors who are not having a book.

> Important: My AR version doesn't have left_outer_joins method

Comment: What is the output you're trying for?

Comment: To find the book count of each author (there are authors without books as well) and order on the book count.

Comment: @ShanakaKuruwita So you mean it should include authors who don't have books but the books_count should be 0. is it?

Comment: @Vishal exactly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more query which will check if author don't have books then we will need to add it. please try below query

```
 Author.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN authors on books.author_id = authors.id")
.merge(Book.available)
.where("books.author_id IS NULL")
.select("authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count")
.group("authors.id").order("books_count")
```

Comment: this seem like a good approach, but this where will add an AND operator to where clause to not OR. So I'm ended up getting no results. 'or' method is not available in my version.

Comment: @ShanakaKuruwita  `or` method isn't available in your version means? you have to use OR in query. did you try above query or you made changes in your existing query?

Comment: yes I tried your exact query. what meant was Model.where.or here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions

Comment: @ShanakaKuruwita  But why you want to use active record's `or` method when you can simply use `or` with above query. i think above query will work 100%. you don't need to lookup for any other active record methods

Comment: This is the query I get :- Select authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count 
From authors left outer join books on books.author_id = authors.id 
where ( books.available = true ) AND ( books.author_id IS NULL )
group by (authors.id) order by books_count;

Answer (score 0):

While it does not use your scope. (mostly because your scope includes a where clause that you do not want as part of your query)

You could do this with `arel` such as:

```
book_table = Book.arel_table
author_table = Author.arel_table
author_join = author_table.join(book_table,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
  .on(book_table[:author_id].eq(author_table[:id]).and(
       book_table[:available].eq(true)
    )
  )
Author.joins(author_join.join_sources)
  .select("authors.* , count(books.*) as books_count")
  .group("authors.id").order("books_count")
```

This will result in the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  authors.* , 
  count(books.*) as books_count
FROM 
  authors 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN books ON books.author_id = authors.id
    AND books.available = true
GROUP BY 
  authors.id
ORDER BY 
  books_count
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is on Rails 4.2 then if you want true left_outer_joins support just install the [gem "brick"](https://github.com/lorint/brick) and it automatically adds the Rails 5.0 implementation of `left_outer_joins`.  You would probably want to turn off the rest of its functionality, that is unless you want an automatic "admin panel" kind of thing available in your app!